# Firebase Authentication via Phone Number Sign-in Service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my application I am going with a functionality, in which i need to authorize user's mobile number via OTP.

So, for this i need to authentic mobile number via **OTP Call using Firebase Service.** Currently I am doing research but, not able to find any solution regarding **OTP Verification via call with Firebase.**

I have already implemented this functionality using **Firebase Authentication phone number sign-in service** with SMS verification method.

Any source/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Currently firebase does not have OTP over call service they have only SMS for OTP.

Comment: @akshaybhange That sounds like an answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently firebase **does not provide OTP over call**, you'll have to use only SMS OTP service or look for other OTP over call service providers like [twilio](https://www.twilio.com) or [nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/)
Note: I haven't tried any of these. I just Googled for OTP over call service providers. Please search before you select one.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication doesn't provide OTP call verification as of now.